# handleChange with React/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this dropdown menu with MUI

I am trying to return a different Grid containing a different component, in this case Residential or Commercial
depending on which value from the dropdown is selected with my handleBuilding method.

I know this is bad React practice so any other suggestions are welcomed but I would also like to fix it this way.

```
const quote = () => {

const [value, setValue] = useState('residential');

function handleBuilding(){
    console.log('test')    
}

if(value === 'residential') {
    return(
        <Grid container>
            <Grid item md={2}>
            <FormControl fullWidth>
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Select Building</InputLabel>
                <Select>
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleBuilding} value="residential">Residential</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleBuilding} value="commercial">Commercial</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleBuilding} value="corporate">Corporate</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleBuilding} value="hybrid">Hybrid</MenuItem>
                </Select>
                </FormControl>
                <Residential />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    )
}
if(value === 'commercial') {
    return(
        <Grid container>
            <Grid item md={2}>
            <FormControl fullWidth>
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Select Building</InputLabel>
                <Select>
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleBuilding} value="residential">Residential</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleBuilding} value="commercial">Commercial</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleBuilding} value="corporate">Corporate</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleBuilding} value="hybrid">Hybrid</MenuItem>
                </Select>
                </FormControl>
                <Commercial />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
   
    )
}
```

Comment: You should pass the value you are trying to set. So either pass the value to `handleBulding()` and adjust that method accoringly or directly use `onClick={() => setValue("commercial")}`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. im not really sure what "So instead either pass the value to handleBulding() and adjust that method accoringly" means I'm really new to this @Mushroomator

Comment: You could use `const handleBuilding = (newValue) => setValue(newValue);` and then call `onClick={() => handleBuilding("commercial")}` or you could just set the value directly in `onClick` like I showed you above `onClick={() => setValue("commercial")}`.

Comment: Usually you would also hold the select options in an object or array and use `map()` to render them. This way you just need to add an element to the array/ object which you could e.g. do by configuration and you would be much more flexible than hard-coding all options into your component here. This would make maintaining the application much easier as these kind of things tend to change regularly

Comment: yeah I tried map but I didn't succeed. calling with onClick worked but lets say I select residential it works then I switch to commercial the commercial component appears but when I go back to residential it stays on the commercial component, if that makes sens @Mushroomator